# Tips and tricks for minimization problem

Tags: numerics, excel, mathematical-optimization

I am quite new to Mathematica and would like to use it for a minimization problem.
The function I like to minimize is:

```
f1[K13_, MOA_, MOB_] := (((K13*R13Bm*
       mB)/((K13*R13Bm + 
         1)*((K13*M13*R13Bm + M12)/(K13*R13Bm + 1) + 
         2*MOB)) + (K13*R13Am*
       mA)/((K13*R13Am + 
         1)*((K13*M13*R13Am + M12)/(K13*R13Am + 1) + 
         2*MOA)))/(mB/((K13*R13Bm + 
         1)*((K13*M13*R13Bm + M12)/(K13*R13Bm + 1) + 2*MOB)) + 
    mA/((K13*R13Am + 1)*((K13*M13*R13Am + M12)/(K13*R13Am + 1) + 
         2*MOA))) - K13*R13ABm)^2;
```

I do know these variables.

```
M12 = 12;
M13 = 13.00335483521;

mA = 1.015;
mB = 1.005;

R13Am = 0.0106103047279518;
R13Bm = 40.9663865546218;
R13ABm = 0.948868038336474000;
```

For the minimization, I use the following line, which also includes the conditions I know.
I use different methods since I do not know which performs the best in my case.

```
MinO = 15.99491462;
MaxO = 17.9991596128;

Print[NMinimize[{f1[K13, MOA, MOB], K13 < 2, MinO < MOA < MaxO, 
 MinO < MOB < MaxO}, {K13, MOA, MOB}, MaxIterations -> 10^6, 
Method -> #] & /@ {"NelderMead", "DifferentialEvolution", "SimulatedAnnealing", "RandomSearch"}]
```

Since the data set is made up, I know the true results these are:

```
trueK = 0.952;
trueMOA = 16.04352070264570000;
trueMOB = 17.02411241055510000;
```

Actually, f1 of my true value should be exactly zero. If I calculate f1[trueK,trueMOB,trueMOB] in EXCEL it is exactly 0, but with Mathematica it is something like 2.08309*10^-30, which is quite close to zero. None of the above methods finds the true solution, I have also plotted the function and the issue seems to be that f1 is quite flat. Is there some kind of standard procedure for such cases? Also, if I use the solutions found by one of the methods and calculate f1 in EXCEL I get a different result, is the precision of Mathematic that better than EXCEL's?
I did check whether my EXCEL function and my function in Mathematica are the same. They are and for "extreme" examples like f1[1,1,1] they calculate the same value.

Comment: What are the values of MinO and MaxO ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot them. Now they are right above the NMinimize command.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution, than presented by you, is produced through

```
NMinimize[{f1[K13, MOA, MOB], K13 < 2, MinO < MOA < MaxO, 
MinO < MOB < MaxO}, {K13, MOA, MOB}, 
Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 0.6},WorkingPrecision -> 60]
```

> `{0, {K13 ->  0.974091537505626338413454936585033099795440154756353089313755,  MOA -> 16.\ 0982779097523456671283714658521448890358670599144209818258,  MOB -> 16.\ 5661836142383248676421256702600498151171079516988921378987}}`

All that is art for art's sake. Such precision is not from real life.